# Как реализовать выполнение одной части кода, при каком-то условии?

Tags: python

К примеру!

Есть код:

```
while True:
    a = input('Введи команду:')
    if a == 'магазин':
        print('Чтобы купить напишите 1')
    elif a == '1':
        print('Вы купили')
    else:
        continue
```

нужно сделать так, чтобы действие с покупкой выполнялось пока ты находишься условно в 'Магазине'. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ещё один while. Вложенный.

Comment: приведите пример того, что должно выполняться при вводе 'магазин'

Comment: finally, смотри. Я делаю игрового бота для вк! В магазине находятся какие-то товары! Нужно сделать так, чтобы эти товары можно было купить, находясь именно в магазине

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По заветам @Akina, странно, что у вас возникли сложности

```
while True:
   a = input('Введи команду:\t')
   if a == 'магазин':
      while a != '0':
         a = input('Чтобы купить 1, чтобы выйти 0\t')
         if a == '1':
            print('Что-то купили')
```